# how to get a reference for the caller element when the function has already a parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, reference, call

```
function myFunction(par) {
...
}


el1.onclick=myFunction(5);
el2.onclick=myFunction(7);
```

How to get a reference for the caller element inside `myFunction`?

Comment: FYI You probably are asking about the _target_ element, not the _caller_.  The term _caller_ refers to the function from which the currently executing function was called.  Many JS engines have a property of the arguments object, called `caller` [though this is now considered obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//this is saying call this function and asign what it returns to onclick
    el1.onclick= myFunction(5);

You want to use a closure
    el1.onclick = function(){myFunction(5);}

To reference the element you can pass the object in

```
function test(elem, x){    
    elem.innerHTML = x;
} 

document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(){ test(this, 1); }
```

[example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/T7bpn/)

or you can use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) so that within the listener, `this` references the element.

```
function test(x){    
    this.innerHTML = x;
}

document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(){ test.call(this, 1); }
```

[example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/V9xCx/1/)

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you are assigning the return value from `myFunction(5)` to `el1.onclick`, and the return value from `myFunction(7)` to `el2.onclick`.

Take the following example:

```
el1.onclick=myFunction(5);
```

In the above example, `myFunction(5)` is executed.  Then the return value of that function, let's call it myval, is assigned to `el1.onclick`.  This is equivalent to:

```
var myval = myFunction(5);
el1.onclick = myval;
```

It's not clear that this is what you intended.  For this to work, the return value from myFunction would need to be a *function* (or a string of Javascript) to be executed later.

It is inside *that* function that you would refer to the caller element.  `this` inside that function will return the element on which the event is currently being called.